# Setting default index in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I can't define default index in Kibana 4.0.2, as you can see on the image below. It doesn't saves if I enter it manually in "Advanced" tab, it only glitches when I click on "Set as default index" button but it doesn't make needed changes.

I'm using Couchbase 3.0.3, transport-couchbase plugin 2.0, ElasticSearch 1.5.2.

I've tried reinstalling everything (except couchbase), one by one, always the same.
I've googled it whole day, nothing. Someone has any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

it seems your not the only one having this issue with couchbase => https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3331#issuecomment-84942136

Comment: I've seen that one and that's the only page I've found that mentions this.
But, check out the bottom of it.

"rashidkpc commented on Mar 25
Thanks for the update, closing as this was caused by a user template."

"rjshah commented on Mar 26
This change is not working."

Well, it's not working for me either...

Comment: do you have a couchbase template so ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's there by default. And I've tried changing it as suggested, no luck.

Comment: could you provide a link to this template please ? (pastebin, ...)

Comment: I've tried changing "template" : "*"  to something different like "template" : "cb-*", but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

After changing couchbase_template.json it's needed to set

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/couchbase -d @/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/transport-couchbase/couchbase_template.json
```

and now it works. 
Thnx [juliendangers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1478667/juliendangers) for directions.